In Next.js 14 can a component be pre-loaded or set with priority?
Building my first Next.js 14 site I'm looking to learn how I can better implement site performance. In my layout.tsx I have a header component
layout.tsx (stripped down example)
import '@/styles/globals.css'

import Header from 'Header'
import Footer from 'Footer'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
          <Header /> // priority here?
          <main className="grow"> // lazy load everything below?
            {children}
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

and I was wondering similar to images with Priority is there a way to set priority for the entire Header component but everything else with the site be lazy loaded even if I'm building RSC?
Closest topic on this I could find was: "Lazy Load React Server Components"
Looked to see if this was available in the docs with no luck:

Adding priority prop for  component 
Script
Script Optimization

In Next.js 14 with app router is there an ability to set a priority on a component level and not just an image level that would allow everything below the above-the-fold to be lazy loaded?

After a further dive into Next.js documentation I was able to find Lazy Loading that talks about using dynamic imports with next/dynamic:

next/dynamic is a composite of React.lazy() and Suspense. It behaves the same way in the app and pages directories to allow for incremental migration.

So I can do:
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

import '@/styles/globals.css'

import Header from 'Header'

// dynamic here
const Footer = dynamic(() => import('Footer'), {
  loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
})

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
          <Header /> 
          <main className="grow">
            {children}
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}


You can use Suspense in NextJS to not block and display a "loading" widget while any async operation finishes for a specific component allowing you Header to be displayed while the app fetches whatever data to display afterwards.
For example:
export default async Fuction MyComponent(...) 
{
 const asyncData = await GetData();
 return <div>{asyncData.Somethin}</div>
}

export default function Layout(...)
{
returnu     <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
          <Header /> // priority here?
          <main className="grow"> // lazy load everything below?
            {children}
            <Suspense loading="<div>Loading</div>">
              <MyComponent.../>
            </Suspense>
          </main> 
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
}

You also got loading boundaries when using these, you can make sure you root layout always loads and any sub-page/layout will display whatever is inside the loading.tsx until all the async data in the page is loaded, causing you header to show before any other data is streamed in and you get the added benefit of showing some place-holder data or animation  while all is build.
In a nutshell you structure could look like
- app
  - layout.txs 
  - page.txs -> Suspend would go here for anything blocking in page.tsx
  test-path/
     - layout.tsx
     - page.tsx
     - loading.tsx -> When defining the loading state, when visiting youpage.com/test-path the layout.tsx would load and therfore the Header, then whatever inside the loading.tsx will display until page.tsx is ready


Doesn't Suspense mean I would not be able to use server components and would have to use use client for all children components of the header?

You can use Suspense in Server Components fine, use client is only necessary in nextjs 14 when you want to use hooks/events

If you however, want for example a button to load more data in the app when clicked, then yes you will need a client component that holds the button and on click fetch more data form the server and displays it. You can use server actions for that.
